# How to escape % in printfn / sprintf?

Tags: f#

How can you print text with an actual % sign in it using printf/sprintf ? e.g.

```
let fn = 5
printf "%i%" fn
```

gives a compile error. The obvious `\%` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use "%%" where you want the % in the output text.

From the example above

```
let fn = 5
printf "%i%%" fn
```

will happily print "5%"

(Also if you want to print "%5" for some reason, the only way I found is to concatenate strings i.e.

```
"%"+ (printf "%i" 5)
```

because

```
printf "%%%i" 5
```

will not work either.)

Comment: Worth noting that there was a bug in the initial F# 3.1 release where `printfn "%%"` started printing "%%" instead of just "%". If anyone happens to encounter this, the 3.1.1 and subsequent updates fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do something like:

```ml
let fn = 5
printf "%i%s" fn "%"
```